# Keras ValueError while loading a saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to build a chatbot using keras in tensorflow. I'm using an encoder and a decoder, and in order to prevent the model from retraining itself every time I want to run chat.py (the file that initializes a chatbot instance), I'm trying to save the encoder and decoder models from another file, rather than importing them.

Cue my issue. Whenever I try to load the models in chat.py, like so:

```
encoder_model = load_model('encoder_model.keras')
decoder_model = load_model('decoder_model.keras')
```

I get the following error, specifically for loading the decoder_model:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Layer node index out of bounds.
inbound_layer = <LSTM name=lstm_1, built=True>
inbound_layer._inbound_nodes = [<Node operation=<LSTM name=lstm_1, built=True>, id=140152069537264>]
inbound_node_index = 1
```

.

The following is the chunk of code I used to train decoder_model in test_model.py:

```
latent_dim = 256
# Establish the decoder input hidden and cell states, and combine
# in a list.
decoder_state_input_hidden = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_cell = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_hidden, decoder_state_input_cell]

decoder_outputs, state_hidden, state_cell = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_hidden, state_cell]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)

# Save the models to .keras files
decoder_model.save("decoder_model.keras")
decoder_model.summary()
```

Is there a step I'm missing between saving the decoder_model and loading it with keras.models.load_model()?

I've tried using .h5 files instead of .keras files, as well as deleting all saved model files and having my code generate them again; none of this resulted in any change in the error. When I comment out the decoder_model assignation in chat.py, the error goes away (though this isn't a fix because I need that model for the rest of the code to run--it just narrows down that decoder_model is the issue, rather than encoder_model).